# javascript setinterval crash explorer 11 tab

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am re-doing an old java applet of mine as javascript.  I want to display a simple animation that changes every few seconds.  I have a test thing working but it crashes the tab after a while in internet explorer 11.

I am using canvas and have this html:

```
<script src="jsfnn2.js"></script>
<body onload="init();">
<canvas id="tutorial" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

and the (maybe) relevant parts of the javascript are:

```
function init() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

...

function draw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('tutorial');

    ...

    if (canvas.getContext) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ...

    }
setInterval( draw, 2000);
}
init();
```

So I put the setInterval just inside the draw function at the end.  Is that the right place?  Seems wrong to call a function from within the same function.

And it's pretty clear I just stole most of this from the canvas tutorial on Mozilla.org.  I usually write in R and python, I just thought this was in javascript's wheelhouse, so I'd try it.  I don't plan to do a lot with canvas, just wanted this working politely in explorer 11 (which I'm forced to use at work - don't ask :/).  Ok, enough explaining why I'm a lazy idiot.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instinct is correct. Using `setInterval()` *inside* the interval callback means you're creating a *new* interval timer each tick.  After a few cycles there will be thousands of them, because each one of those redundant timers will also create more redundant timers for the same reason.

If you change that to `setTimeout()`, it would work. The `setTimeout()` mechanism just goes for one delay period and does not repeat.

Also, there's not much point to starting the process via `requestAnimationFrame()` if the actual cycle is 2 seconds long, but it won't hurt anything.

Comment: setTimeout() did indeed work like a charm, thanks. Also the requestAnimationFrame() messed it up a bit.  The animation was supposed to move each square one space and was moving it two.  I took it out and just called draw() and it worked as expected.  Thanks!